# After my computer crashed while compiling, my file suddenly does not compile. It says font missing

Tags: fonts, fontspec, texstudio

Sorry everyone. I do not really know if this belongs here, but I can't find a solution by myself, since I have no idea of what could be happening here! I have the fonts installed, but TexStudio says they are missing! How could I start solving this problem?

Comment: TeXstudio is a front end to a TeX distribution, not a TeX distribution itself. You need to reinstall not TeXstudio but also a suitable TeX distribution.

Comment: So should I reinstall both Miktex and TexStudio? Is there a way to only reinstall Miktex?

Comment: The answer to your first question is "yes". I don't understand the point of yur secomd question.

Comment: Oh well if that's how it is I will do it. I was trying to avoid reinstalling Texstudio since I remember it was an awful experience getting everything to work and I have many custom configurations and macros I will loose.